# Removing parts of values within a columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Say I have column `b` in a dataframe `df`.
The column b looks like,

```
b
c'ASD56y'
c'DSAD89y'
c'FGTH89y'
```

I need to remove the single quotes and c from the column b.I need the output like,

```
 b
    ASD56y
    DSAD89y
    FGTH89y
```

Here is what I tried,

```
 df.b.apply(lambda x: x.strip('c'))
```

which is throwing the error as:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please determine the type of data for that column and post it? It doesn't look like a standard string, nor like a byte string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `split` can do it

```
df.b.str.split("'").str[1]
Out[93]: 
0     ASD56y
1    DSAD89y
2    FGTH89y
Name: b, dtype: object
df.b=df.b.str.split("'").str[1]
```

---

Base on the comments below , the problem turn to be `encode`\ `decode`

```
df['b'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, no, it is throwing error, as `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: @user1017373 using df.b.to_dict() show us your data here , I running via your sample data no error pop-up

Comment: Apparently, those values are the string representations of something funky.  You'll have to provide a way to recreate your data that still reproduces your problem.

Comment: The toy is data is from a big dataset and here is the dictionary look of from the big dataset 
```{0: b'ENF009',
 1: b'ENF3',
 2: b'ENF3',
 3: b'ENF4',
 }
```

Comment: @WeNYoBen Thanks and how to address that problem,

Comment: @user1017373 you should try `df['b'].str.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 1):

Just be sure you [decode](https://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/) the values of your dict before making the DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> toy = {0: b'ENF009', 1: b'ENF3', 2: b'ENF3', 3: b'ENF4'}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([v.decode() for v in toy.values()], index=toy.keys())
>>> print(df)
        0
0  ENF009
1    ENF3
2    ENF3
3    ENF4
```